# $\operatorname{Ind}(\pi \otimes \chi|_H) = \operatorname{Ind}(\pi) \otimes H$

Tags: representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ind}{Ind}$Let $H$ be a subgroup of finite index of a group $G$.  Let $\chi: G \rightarrow \mathbb C^{\ast}$ be a character of $G$, and $(\pi,V)$ a representation of $H$.  Is it true that

$$\Ind(\pi \otimes \chi|_H) \cong \Ind(\pi) \otimes \chi$$

as representations of $G$?

The space of the left hand side consists of all functions $f: G \rightarrow V$ such that $f(hg) = \pi(h) \chi(h)f(g)$, on which $G$ acts by right translation.  The space of the right hand side consists of all functions $f: G \rightarrow V$ such that $f(hg) = \pi(h)f(g)$, on which $G$ acts by $g \cdot f(x) = \chi(g)f(xg)$.

I have seen notes which identify these spaces, but are they really the same?

Comment: $f \mapsto \chi^{-1}f$